# ember js with ember data, browser back and forward causes reload Models requested with find()

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I just build small app to test a router. Every model is loaded once, whenever I asked for it, next time I visit same url by clicking on a link I see cached results. All good, but then I clicked back button on a browser and I saw a request to the server for a model which previously was asked with `find()` a.k.a. `findAll()`. And this happens every time I click back or forward button on a browser, no matter if I use `location: 'history'` or `location: 'hash'`

I only have two models, one requested with `find()` and another requested via `find(id)`. So I'm wondering now is this suppose to happen in this way or there is some problem with my app that I should look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure that is not how it should be working. We have an app that uses location: 'history' and along with several models and they remain cached when user clicks back/forward in the browser.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see no delay for displaying the data on screen, not like first time loading the page, so I assuming that data is cached, but I can see that every time I click back/forward, browser connects to the server, which is weird and confusing. I'm using slightly modified RESTAdaptor, but I'm not sure if adaptor ir the one to blame here.

Comment: That makes sense. It's not related to forward/back buttons, but Ember is going to query the server (to check for new records) whenever you call find(). The first time you'd see a delay, as the list of items is empty until the server returns. It won't call the server for find(id) if a record with that id has already been loaded. To debug, try adding some debug messages around anyplace that you've called find() and see if it is being called when you expect.

Comment: You're right, I just tried to add additional entry into the database and clicked back on the browser, the list were repopulated with new information. Thanks!